# ColdFusion CF2021 xmlParse(file) returning wddx encoded object

Tags: coldfusion, wddx

UPDATE: After doing some more poking around, it looks as though the problem has to do with where CF is looking for the DTD file referenced in the XML.

We have the DTDs, but it looks as though CF isn't finding them, so it isn't sure how to parse the XML according to the DTD.  I determined this by having it parse XML without any DTD, and it worked as expected and as I wanted - returning a parsed xmlDoc, not a string.

Is there some way of setting the default directory for where CF should look for the DTD specified in the XML?

---

We're running CF2021, and xmlParse(file), which should return a parsed XML object is instead returning the file contents as a string, inside a wddx encoded object.  We have just migrated from a CF2018 server running on a remote hosting service to CF2021 running on an AWS box.

In order to return the XML object we need, I need to run xmlParse on the file, then wddx2cfml on the object, then xmlParse again on the string.

Is there a reason why xmlParse, which should return a parsed XML object, is instead behaving this way?

We pass the system file location to the method.  Call it docPath, and it'd look something like g:\appName\xmlFiles\20230125.xml

Then we have, in cfscript:
   `doc = xmlParse(docPath);`

When I dump that to a file, I get what I described above.  When I change it to the following, I get what  want:
   `docFile = xmlParse(docPath); cfwddx(action="wddx2cfml", input="#docFile#", output="xmlString"); xmlDoc = xmlParse(xmlString);`
But I don't understand why this is necessary, and I'm concerned about having to change it everywhere in the code that we use xmlParse.  For the record, this also occurs in tagged CF as well as cfscript, so it's not that.

Comment: Can you pls give us a portable / runnable example of what you're talking about, so we can see? (guidance: http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Really there in the description:

File 20230125.xml contains well-formed XML.

docPath = "g:\appName\xmlFiles\20230125.xml";
docFile = xmlParse(docPath); 
cfwddx(action="wddx2cfml", input="#docFile#", output="xmlString"); 
xmlDoc = xmlParse(xmlString);

In other code, docFile would be an XML document.  Now, it's a string inside a wddx object, and I need to add the last two lines to get an xml doc.

Comment: I think @AdamCameron is saying... "let's see the XML".

Comment: I'm not trying to be deliberately mysterious here, but while the format isn't proprietary, the content certainly is.

But I can easily give you the header information:
```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE REQUEST_GROUP SYSTEM="eRegistry_eDelivery_Request_v3_0_0.dtd">
```

The only other potential odd thing is that the lines in the encrypted signature block end in &#13;

But all of this worked before.  All I can say is that the XML has been checked and is well-formatted.

Comment: Did you read the link I posted? Noone care about your proprietary stuff, and that will not likely contribute to your situation. Just give us an example (you might need to contrive it yourself) that we can run to see the problem. Edit the question and put the code into it, rather than adding a comment as well, so it's easier for ppl to spot. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the dtd files in CF's WEB-INF folder solved the problem.  CF was able to match the DTD with the DOCTYPE and properly parse the XML.

Comment: This should not have mattered; XML doesn't need a DTD to be parsed, so not sure this is actually the solution to the question. However we still don't have enough to go on to actually reason it through ;-)